# Object3D scale and Sprite scale do not match

Tags: three.js

Why is it when an object is created with THREE.Mesh, the scale property acts completely different than when THREE.Sprite is used? A sprite with its scale property's set to 1 is not able to be seen.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle that shows the issue?

Comment: Sure I hope a codepen is ok if not let me know. The Mesh has a scale of 1. The sprite has a scale of 30. But some how the Mesh is larger. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emzoXo

Comment: You're creating a 50x50 plane `new THREE.PlaneGeometry(50, 50, 3, 3);` and scaling it by 1. The sprite is of unit 1 scaled by 30. Of course the mesh is bigger (50 vs 30).